# Comparing against a regex passed into awk as a variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I create the following awk example script in order to add the line - "line 1"
after the line "**target**"

we set the variable var="**target**" , to export the value target inside the awk,

But when we run the script , seems that awk not read the value in **var**

The script with awk:

```
[root@master tmp]# more test.bash
#!/bin/bash


awk -v var="target" '1; done != 1 && /var/ {
                print "line 1"
                done = 1
                }' file
```

The file:

```
[root@master tmp]# more file


target
```

When I run the script we get:

```
[root@master tmp]# ./test.bash


target
```

While expected results should be

```
target
line 1
```

I will happy to know what I am wrong with awk syntax,

And how to fix it so var inside the awk will get the value - "target"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `/var/` (which looks only for the exact string `var`, not at the contents of the variable thus named), use the `~` operator:

```
awk -v var="$target" '
1 { print }
done != 1 && $0 ~ var { print "line 1"; done=1 }
' file
```

Comment: excellent answer and so simple solution , thank you so much